# ArangoDB Foxx Repository JSON Parsing issue

Tags: json, arangodb, foxx

I've a problem in parsing a JSON message in my Foxx application in ArangoDB.

This is the code for the "post" in the controller:

```
controller.post('/', function (req, res) {
        var message = req.params("testCollection");
        var data = message.records;
        for(var i in data) {
           var imei = data[i].imei;
           var timestamp = data[i].timestamp;

           ....other stuff here using place and timestamp
       }
}
```

This is the JSON message:

```
{
    "records": [
      {
        "timestamp": "2001/05/09",
        "imei": "123456789012345",
        "gpsData": {
            "lat": 1001,
            "lon": 1002,
            "altitude": 1003,
            "speed": 1004
        },
        "io": [
            {"key": "IO1", "value": 1},
            {"key": "IO2", "value": 2},
            {"key": "IO3", "value": 3},
            {"key": "IO4", "value": 4},
            {"key": "IO5", "value": 5},
            {"key": "IO6", "value": 6},
            {"key": "IO7", "value": 7}
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `imei` is then used as parameter for a query but I can't get any response.
If I hardcode the `imei` I can get the proper document from the collection.

Is there anything wrong in the above code to parse the JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed by replacing the following code:

```
var data = message.records;
```

with:

```
var data = message.get('records');
```